# angular app deployment after adding changes

Tags: firebase, web-deployment, angularfire2, angularfire, firebase-hosting

I'm deploying my angular 10 app to firebase hosting. This is my first time deploying an app so I have a couple of questions.

1. If I make changes to my app, do I have to create a new build and deploy that new build?
2. I know angular coverts ts files to js once it is deployed, so how do I add changes to those files at that point, if needed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you make a change to the app, you'll have to rebuild it, and deploy the results of that build.

If you're deploying JS files that are built from TS files, the build step will rebuild updated JS files in the above process, and those updated files are then deployed.